# How can I tell if my device supports phone calls in a Xamarin app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, phone-call, xamarin.essentials

### Summary

I would like to be able to tell if a device supports phone calls so that I can hide the call button. Is this possible in a Xamarin app? I am interested in both an iOS and Android solution.

### Details

I am placing phone calls using Xamarin.Essentials PhoneDialer as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/phone-dialer?tabs=ios.

The documentation recommends surrounding the PhoneDialer.Open call with exceptions to report information to the user about the phone dialer failing. While this does work, I would like to hide the button on devices which do not have the ability to make calls (such as ipads).

Is there a way to detect whether a device can make a call without attempting to open the phone dialer?

Comment: I don't think it's that clear cut.  iPads can use FaceTime to make calls.  And an iPhone could have its SIM card removed, disabling the ability to make normal calls.  You could check the device idiom and make a best-guess based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Xamarin.Essentials PhoneDialer Class [PhoneDialer Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.phonedialer?view=xamarin-essentials)

You will have to use the PhoneDialer.Open(String) Method

```
        try  
        {  
            PhoneDialer.Open(number);  
        }  

        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)  
        {  
            // Phone Dialer is not supported on this device.  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            // Other error has occurred.  
        }
```

In the FeatureNotSupportedException you will be able to tell if the device supports phone calls or not.